# PDFBox throws exception when displaying currency symbol other than USD $

Tags: pdf, utf-8, pdf-generation, pdfbox

We're in the process of internationalizing our application and we use PDFBox 2.0.7.

We are trying to use the Costa Rican colon ₡ in PDFBox but it throws an exception that says: "No glyph for U+010D in font HelvetiaNeueLT-Roman"

We've inspected the ttf font file and the font indeed does have the Costa Rican currency symbol.

Comment: Please include some code and test it with some standard font (e.g. Arial, Courier, Times) so that we can reproduce it. Is the message "No glyph for U+010D in font HelvetiaNeueLT-Roman" the complete message or did it also mention something about WinAnsiEncode?

Comment: I was able to include the ₡ in a PDF file by using Arial and Liberation, and loading the font with `PDType0Font.load(document, new File("LiberationSans-Regular.ttf"));`

Comment: This is now 5 days ago. Did any comment help you?

Comment: The issue was that we were including a font that did not have the necessary glyphs. (latin chars only) Downloading and including full font worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that; to avoid orphans, either answer the question yourself if you think it may help others, or delete the question.